# Change OpenID on data.SE

Tags: bug, data-explorer, stack-exchange-openid

I'm trying to change the OpenID of my data.SE account, but when I click the "Log in using Stack Exchange" button I get redirected to a page saying "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime Error".

I'm using Firefox 39 on Linux Mint. Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to profile page on data.stackexchange.com.
2. Click on "change openid".
3. Click on "Log in using Stack Exchange".

Below are screenshots of these steps and the error page I am
redirected to when clicking "Log in using Stack Exchange".

[image: "change openid"]
[image: "Log in using Stack Exchange"]
[image: Error page]

Comment: Urgh. I really need to stop putting off polishing up the auth, will see if I can get this sorted in a few hours.

Comment: Did you originally log in with Google?

Comment: @TimStone I think I did, and then wanted to tie the account to my SE account.

Comment: Alright, thanks! This'll probably be fixed [with this update I'm working on](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261181/two-sede-accounts-please-fix-and-how-do-i-avoid-this/264145#264145) then (though for a different reason than I described there), sorry about the inconvenience/wait.